# Blender Rigging: Mirrors Changes

Tags: armature

I have a character body made and im getting it ready for animation in Iclone 6.Im at the Armature stage in blender.The problem is when i test it in pose mode.It mirrors the bone movements to the other side as well and it look all deformed.The left side of the arms and legs dont move with the armature.Im thinking its caused by the mirror modifier i put on the mesh but,Im not sure.  Please help.

Comment: Its not clear which mode you're in when the mirroring error occurs.

Answer (score 1):

To prevent the bones from mirroring , you just have to uncheck "X-Axis Mirror" in the tool panel, while in armature edit mode.

[image]

Comment: It is unchecked but still it mirrors